# how do I subtract 24 hour from date time object in PHP

Tags: php, datetime

I have the following code:

```
  $now = date("Y-m-d H:m:s");
  $date = date("Y-m-d H:m:s", strtotime('-24 hours', $now));
```

However, now it gives me this error:

```
A non well formed numeric value encountered in...
```

why is this?

Comment: See the manual - `strtotime` expects a timestamp as the second value. (In your example, you could just omit it completely)

Comment: You might want to consideer day time saving borders: do you really want a swith from 10 AM to 11 AM (or 9 AM?).

Comment: ...did anyone else catch that `m` is where `i` usually sits in the time portion?  Every one of the answers copy pasted this oversight. Ha.

Comment: @mickmackusa You are absolutely right. Minutes are formatted with `i`, `m` are months

Comment: Why have't you accepted an answer to this very basic and very well recived question? Doing so would help others. Btw, I think that @Joel has given the best answer.

Answer (score 66):

```
$date = (new \DateTime())->modify('-24 hours');
```

or

```
$date = (new \DateTime())->modify('-1 day');
```

(The latter takes into account [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718107/how-do-i-subtract-24-hour-from-date-time-object-in-php/17718175#comment25824515_17718107) as it is a valid point.)

Should work fine for you here. See http://PHP.net/datetime

$date will be an instance of [DateTime](http://php.net/datetime), a real DateTime object.

Comment: this answer modifies the original DateTime object in-place.

Comment: Yes, that's the way \DateTime works. If that isn't good for you, use \DateTimeImmutable instead.

Comment: ah thank you! didn't know DateTimeImmutable was a thing.

Answer (score 54):

`strtotime()` expects a unix timestamp (which is `number seconds since Jan 01 1970`)

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('-24 hours', time())); ////time() is default so you do not need to specify.
```

i would suggest using the datetime library though, since it's a more object oriented approach.

```
$date = new DateTime(); //date & time of right now. (Like time())
$date->sub(new DateInterval('P1D')); //subtract period of 1 day
```

The advantage of this is that you can reuse the `DateInterval`:

```
$date = new DateTime(); //date & time of right now. (Like time())
$oneDayPeriod = new DateInterval('P1D'); //period of 1 day
$date->sub($oneDayPeriod);
$date->sub($oneDayPeriod); //2 days are subtracted.
$date2 = new DateTime(); 
$date2->sub($oneDayPeriod); //can use the same period, multiple times.
```

### Carbon (update 2020)

Most popular library for processing DateTimes in PHP is [Carbon](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/).

Here you would simply do:

```
$yesterday = Carbon::now()->subDay();
```

Comment: This is the only answer given which uses `DateTime->sub()`, whcih is the correct way to subtract from a  DateTime. Upvote - this ought to have been the accepted answer.

Answer (score 11):

you can do this in many ways...

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('-24 hours')); // "i" for minutes with leading zeros
```

OR

```
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s',strtotime('last day')); // 24 hours (1 day)
```

**Output**

```
2013-07-17 10:07:29
```

Comment: The big difference does your application expect a string or an object. If string then the string way is fine but if object then you have to use DateTime. While the output might look the same the data type is not.

Answer (score 5):

Simplest way to sub or add time,

```
<?php
**#Subtract 24 hours**
$dtSub = new DateTime('- 24 hours');
var_dump($dtSub->format('Y-m-d H:m:s'));
**#Add 24 hours**
$dtAdd = new DateTime('24 hours');
var_dump($dtAdd->format('Y-m-d H:m:s'));die;
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

This may be helpful for you:

```
//calculate like this
$date = date("Y-m-d H:m:s", (time()-(60*60*24)));

//check the date
echo $date;
```

Comment: Downvoted for unreliability: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/729ae5a21769fdc06a5c340457d5793f28c04642

Answer (score 2):

this should work, too

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:m:s", strtotime('-24 hours'));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('-24 hours', strtotime($now)));
```

Add "strtotime" before $now,
and Y-m-d H:m:s replace with Y-m-d H:i:s

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use `time()` to get the current timestamp.

```
$date = date("Y-m-d H:m:s", strtotime('-24 hours', time()));
```

Answer (score 1):

In same code use strtotime() its working.

```
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$date = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('-2 hours', strtotime($now)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
$now = time();
$date = date("Y-m-d H:m:s", strtotime('-24 hours', $now));
```

Answer (score 0):

all you have to do is to alter your code to be

```
$now = strtotime(date("Y-m-d H:m:s"));
$date = date("Y-m-d H:m:s", strtotime('-24 hours', $now));
```