# Compare ISO date to current date

Tags: php

I have what I believe are ISO dates (may be wrong) stored in my database:

`2015-01-03T12:30:00.000Z`

I want to check whether that date is greater than 24 hours away.

I've looked at `if($date > new DateTime())` etc, but am a little confused how to achieve this.

Comment: Possible dup? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17718107/how-do-i-subtract-24-hour-from-date-time-object-in-php

Comment: So I use `$date = (new \DateTime())->modify('-24 hours');` except `+24 hours` to get a date 24 hours ahead of now. But I don't know how to get them in the same format. The one stored in my DB is strange with the `T12:30:00.000Z` for time.

Comment: Okay - ended up writing this, think I confused myself. https://gist.github.com/chrisloftus/929d7ee046cfaeab6162

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Date you provided is formated in [ISO-8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601). **Z** at the end stands for Zero/Zulu/+00:00 timezone.

You can compare date using `DateTime` + `modify` + `getTimestamp`

```
$dateString = '2015-01-03T12:30:00.000Z';
$date = new DateTime($dateString);
$dateToCompare = (new DateTime())->modify('+24 hours');

if($date->getTimestamp() < $dateToCompare->getTimestamp()){
    echo 'more than 24 hours away';
}
```

If want to format any date to same format, you have to set timezone to `Z` and use format `"Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z"`

```
$format = "Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z";
$dateToCompare->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('Z'));
echo "\n".$dateToCompare->format($format);
```